# How to simplify multiple nested foreach loops?

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, datagrid

```
 private DataTable GetAttributeTable()
    {
        DataTable cltAttributeTable = new DataTable("CLT_ATTRIBUTE");
        DataColumnCollection iRefColumns = cltAttributeTable.Columns;
        //BETHiddenColumn is defined for hiding certain columns at the UI
        //And can be used for manipulating entities internally
        iRefColumns.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new BETHiddenColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.CLTGUID, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.CLTNAME, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new BETHiddenColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.SHEETID, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.SHEETNAME, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = "OBJECT_NAME", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
            new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = false }
        });
        return cltAttributeTable;
    }

public override async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(ControlNetworkStructure controlNetwork)
    {
        DataTable cltAttributeTable = GetAttributeTable();
        try
        {
            using (var automationService = ConsumedServiceProvider.Provider.AutomationService)
            {
                foreach (string userDefinedLogicTemplate in selectedCLT)
                {
                    var controlLogicClt =
                        automationService.AutomationClt.GetControlLogicTemplate(userDefinedLogicTemplate);
                    foreach (ISheet sheet in await controlLogicClt.GetSheets())
                    {

                        foreach (IFunctionCode functionCode in await sheet.GetFunctionCodes())
                        {
                            foreach (IHarmonyAttribute functionCodeAttribute in functionCode.Attributes)
                            {

                                DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
                                row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = "FUNCTION CODE";
                                row["OBJECT_NAME"] = functionCode.Name;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = functionCodeAttribute.Type;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = functionCodeAttribute.Value;
                                cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (IInputReference inputReference in await sheet.GetInputReferences())
                        {
                            foreach (IHarmonyAttribute functionCodeAttribute in inputReference.Attributes)
                            {

                                DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
                                row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = "IREF";
                                row["OBJECT_NAME"] = inputReference.Name;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = functionCodeAttribute.Type;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = functionCodeAttribute.Value;
                                cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (IOutputReference outputReference in await sheet.GetOutputReferences())
                        {
                            foreach (IHarmonyAttribute functionCodeAttribute in outputReference.Attributes)
                            {

                                DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
                                row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = "OREF";
                                row["OBJECT_NAME"] = outputReference.Name;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = functionCodeAttribute.Type;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = functionCodeAttribute.Value;
                                cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (IText text in await sheet.GetTexts())
                        {
                            foreach (IHarmonyAttribute functionCodeAttribute in text.Attributes)
                            {

                                DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
                                row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = "TEXT";
                                row["OBJECT_NAME"] = text.Name;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = functionCodeAttribute.Type;
                                row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = functionCodeAttribute.Value;
                                cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogService.LogException(this, ServiceResources.CONTEXT_CLD_EDITOR, "CLT Attribute",
                exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Accepting all the modification to the table before leaving this method call
            cltAttributeTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
        return cltAttributeTable;
    }
```

### Description

I have a method with multiple foreach loops inside and I have hard time understanding it as I'm beginner to C#. Also I read its not a good practice to write multiple foreach loops in program.
The method returns a data table and it is bound to a Datagrid. 
Can anyone help me simplify it so that it becomes better readable and more intuitive?

Comment: You can try making a method for each `IHarmonyAttribute` loop. And another method to populate the DataRow, since it's the same every time. You will still have all those loops, but it will look way better and be much more readable.

Comment: You could probably move some of these into complex lambda statements, but I'd say you'd be better off just refactoring the nested blocks into distinct methods.  Ultimately, if you need to traverse a collection then there's not much you can do to avoid that.

Comment: Looking closer, every `IHarmonyAttribute` loop seems to do the same, so with only one Method that needs a `List<IHarmonyAttribute>` or whatever `.Attributes` is as a parameter, you can make a method to reuse it in the `sheet.` loops.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replies. I will try to implement your suggestions. If anyone can help me with sample code , it would help a lot.

Comment: what's the explicit return type of GetFunctionCodes() ? is it dynamic or strongly typed?

Comment: GetFunctionCodes()  returns the list of function codes asynchronously as  Task<IList<IFunctionCode>>

Comment: Are the IFunctionCode, IInputReference, ... based on an common Inerface which exposes the Attributes property or is this published per-interface?

Answer (score 0):

if the Attribute property of the IFunctionCode, IInputReference, etc is based on a common interface, you could do something like this:

```
List<ICommomInterface> items = new List<ICommomInterface>();
items.AddRange(await sheet.GetFunctionCodes());
items.AddRange(await sheet.GetInputReferences());
items.AddRange(await sheet.GetOutputReferences());
items.AddRange(await sheet.GetTexts());

items.foreach(item =>
{
    item.Attributes.ForEach(attrib =>
    {
        DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
        if(item is IFunctionCode){
            row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = "FUNCTION CODE";
        } else if(_other types_)
        {
        }
        row["OBJECT_NAME"] = item.Name;
        row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = attrib.Type;
        row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = attrib.Value;
        cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(row);
    });
});
```

If that's your intention.
If they do not share a common base interface you have to use object class for the list and extend the if(item is IFunctionCode){... check.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will check it day after tomorrow and let you know as its holiday tomorrow and I don't have code access now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is pretty hastily done but I think is a good start. I didn't have time to test it so it probably has some bugs. Also, there's plenty of room for improvements.

```
private DataTable GetAttributeTable()
{
    DataTable cltAttributeTable = new DataTable("CLT_ATTRIBUTE");
    DataColumnCollection iRefColumns = cltAttributeTable.Columns;
    //BETHiddenColumn is defined for hiding certain columns at the UI
    //And can be used for manipulating entities internally
    iRefColumns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new BETHiddenColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.CLTGUID, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.CLTNAME, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new BETHiddenColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.SHEETID, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = CLDConstants.SHEETNAME, DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = "OBJECT_NAME", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = true },
        new DataColumn { ColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_VALUE", DataType = typeof(string), ReadOnly = false }
    });
    return cltAttributeTable;
}

public override async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync(ControlNetworkStructure controlNetwork)
{
    DataTable cltAttributeTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (var automationService = ConsumedServiceProvider.Provider.AutomationService)
        {
            foreach (string userDefinedLogicTemplate in selectedCLT)
            {
                var controlLogicClt =
                    automationService.AutomationClt.GetControlLogicTemplate(userDefinedLogicTemplate);

                cltAttributeTable = await LoopDeLoop(controlLogicClt);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        LogService.LogException(this, ServiceResources.CONTEXT_CLD_EDITOR, "CLT Attribute",
            exception);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Accepting all the modification to the table before leaving this method call
        cltAttributeTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
    return cltAttributeTable;
}

//Main loop with loops adding rows
private async Task<DataTable> LoopDeLoop(dynamic controlLogicClt)
{
    DataTable cltAttributeTable = GetAttributeTable();

    foreach (ISheet sheet in await controlLogicClt.GetSheets())
    {
        foreach (IFunctionCode functionCode in await sheet.GetFunctionCodes())
        {
            cltAttributeTable = GetNewRows(cltAttributeTable, functionCode.Attributes, functionCode.Name, "FUNCTION CODE", controlLogicClt, sheet);
        }

        foreach (IInputReference inputReference in await sheet.GetInputReferences())
        {
            cltAttributeTable = GetNewRows(cltAttributeTable, inputReference.Attributes, inputReference.Name, "IREF", controlLogicClt, sheet);
        }

        foreach (IOutputReference outputReference in await sheet.GetOutputReferences())
        {                           
            cltAttributeTable = GetNewRows(cltAttributeTable, outputReference.Attributes, outputReference.Name, "OREF", controlLogicClt, sheet);                        
        }

        foreach (IText text in await sheet.GetTexts())
        {
            cltAttributeTable = GetNewRows(cltAttributeTable, text.Attributes, text.Name, "TEXT", controlLogicClt, sheet);
        }
    }
}

//Adds the new created rows to the DataTable
private DataTable GetNewRows(DataTable cltAttributeTable, List<IHarmonyAttribute> attributes, string name, string objectType, dynamic controlLogicClt, ISheet sheet)
{
    foreach (IHarmonyAttribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        cltAttributeTable.Rows.Add(GetNewRow(sourceDataRow, attribute, name, objectType, controlLogicClt, sheet));
    }
}

//Creates and populates the new row
private DateRow GetNewRow(IHarmonyAttribute attribute, string name, string objectType, dynamic controlLogicClt, ISheet sheet)
{
        DataRow row = GetRow(cltAttributeTable, controlLogicClt, sheet);
        row["OBJECT_TYPE"] = objectType;
        row["OBJECT_NAME"] = name;
        row["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] = attribute.Type;
        row["ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"] = attribute.Value;   

        return row;         
}
```

So I made three more methods:

`LoopDeLoop` --> This one's for taking out of the main method the majority of the loops and thus making it clearer. Also, it makes the `sheets` loops clearer.

´GetNewRows´ --> This one is for making a common `IHarmonyAttribute` loop and get rid of the need of using four loops.

`GetNewRow` --> This one just populates a new row, but now you don't have to do that four times.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will check it day after tomorrow as its holiday tomorrow and I don't have code access now :)